Retirect to a Wix site from AWS Route 53 subdomain
I have a web application hosted on AWS. I access it by typing something like the following: https://example.com/webapp/login. It has been working fine so far.
I recently created a website on Wix which must use the same domain. The behavior I am trying to achieve is the following:

When typing https://www.example.com -> redirect to wix site
When typing https://example.com -> redirect to wix site (this is not mandatory, but really appreciated)
When typing https://example.com/webapp/login go to the application hosted on AWS.

So far, the only one I could achieve was point 3 and it has been used for months without issues.
The domain is registered in godaddy, but I managed to handle the DNS on AWS Route 53 and it has been working fine with the application itself (point 3), so I think that this is not the problem.
I tried the following (one at a time), all of them on AWS Route 53 DNS:

Add a new NS record for the subdomain www redirecting to the two NS servers provided by Wix
Add a new CNAME record, with subdomain www and redirecting to one of the NS servers provided by Wix (didn't allow me to set 2 ns servers).

In both cases, when I access https://www.example.com on a browser I get the error ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR. The certificate was created on AWS several weeks ago and it works fine for point 3.
If I follow strictly the instructions given on Wix, I should modify the example.com (whithout subdomain) NS record type replacing the four AWS servers with the 2 Wix servers, but I understand that this would redirect everything to Wix, and it would broke the access to my application hosted on AWS.
I would also like to mention that in my AWS Route 53 DNS I have configured records for the business email which is working fine. This is one of the reasons I prefer to keep the AWS DNS instead of switching to Wix DNS.
Do you know what DNS configuration should I do to achieve the mentioned behavior? If necessary, I could use a subdomain for the scenario 3, something like app.example.com which would be an accepted solution, but even in this case I don't know how to make the DNS configuration.
Thank you very much

If multiple redirections are considered, then using Route53 for this is the wrong solution.
I would use a CloudFront distribution. In there, you can setup multiple origins and create rules to direct traffic to your origin of choice:

/webapp/login or /webapp/* -> origin of your application in AWS
(default rule) /* -> origin of your Wix site

Then, you can point to that CloudFront distribution with Route53.

Now that I gave you the general idea, you can expand this by reading AWS documentations.

Thank you very much ivan0kurnia. In case that for the scenario 2. I use a subdomain (app.example.com) it could be solved in AWS Route 53 right? Everything that goes to app.example.com -> redirect to webapp hosted en AWS. Everything that goes to example.com (including www.example.com)-> redirect to wix site. Is it ok? If possible, I prefer using AWS Route 53 rather than cloudfront as I am (a little) more familiar. Thank you for your answer.

@ch87 right, you can do that as well. But you have to make sure your Wix site is the one bringing you to app.example.com. Also, don't forget your CORS.

Thanks ivan. Do you mean that I should use the Wix DNS and add a A record for the subdomain app.example.com? Since I posted the question I have been talking to Wix support and currently I am waiting for the DNS to propagate to check if it works. So far, what I have done is the following, all of them in AWS DNS: 1. Kept the AWS NS as nameservers for the domain. 2. Added an A record for subdomain app. 3. Added a CNAME record for www.example.com redirecting to Wix. 4. Added an A record for example.com which redirects to IP provided by Wix. This is because I want to keep using AWS DNS. Tkank you
